# Software to view flight path of rockets

Tags: spacex, software

What software could a hobbyist use to visualise the flight path of a rocket from launch to some arbitrary time after launch? I imagine this software might draw the path over a globe. Additionally, if possible, I would also like to see the parts of the path where the engines were firing.

Specifically I am interested in seeing the flight path of the Falcon 9 Sentinel 6-Michael Freilich mission, the [live stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVFPzTDCihQ) of the launch showed very little of the actual flight.

I am interested in this launch in particular as I observed a glowing dot in the night sky with  large glowing plume behind it. It looked like a rocket exhaust in low pressure, so I looked up recent rocket launches and came across this mission, and the timeframe seems to match the time I observed it from Southern Africa (approximately 18:20 GMT on the 21st of November). I wanted to see if it was possibly the firing of the second stage that I saw. It would be quite exciting if it was.

Comment: See also [How can I find sources for Launch Trajectories?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25710/12102) and [How can Flightclub.io Camera Tools be used to simulate launch photography geometry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26686/12102) and [Understanding Flightclub.io simulation of SpaceX's Bangabandhu launch](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27230/12102) for example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[flightclub.io](https://flightclub.io) is awesome and Declan is a genius.

Here's the visualization for the Flacon 9 Sentinel 6-Michael Freilich mission that took place on 21<sup>st</sup> November - [Sentinel-6 Michael Freilich Simulation](https://flightclub.io/result/3d?id=e4a4568d-a12a-4174-ad5a-4d312cbeec78). If I am not mistaken by the parallax error, the flight profile did pass over Southern Africa. Check if it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. Looking at the path and the time of second engine cutoff, I highly suspect this is what I saw, Thanks very much

Comment: @Morgoth You're welcome :)

Comment: Everyday Astronaut uses Declan's data to generate simulated telemetry for the F9 first stage (not provided by SpaceX on screen). Generally, touchdown on the drone ship / landing pad in the video feed, and a 0/0 reading on Declan's telemetry seem to match to a degree where you have to pause and single-frame the video to see the difference. It is truly awesome.

Comment: This is amazing Thank you!